# Angular 6 radio buttons unable to group it using name

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have an array

```
dataList = [
      {
        'Country' : 'India',
        'State'  : 'Kasmir'
      },
      {
        'Country' : 'India',
        'State'  : 'Karnataka'
      },
      {
         'Country' : 'Japan',
        'State'  : 'Tokio'
      },
      {
        'Country' : 'Japan',
        'State'  : 'Huwai'
      }
    ]

}
```

I want to make it as two different radio button groups by using Country key or any other way. What I tried is below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList">
       <input type="radio" name="item.Country">{{item.State}}
 </div>
```

It is creating radio buttons and I am using name property to make it separate groups. But it did not working as expected instead I can selectonly one radio button once. 
It  is a sample I have same scenario inside Angular mat-tree. please guide me what to do to make it as group by using name or any other things. Please help me with a generalized solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize Angular's binding syntax.

Either use:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList">
       <input type="radio" [name]="item.Country">{{item.State}}
 </div>
```

or:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList">
       <input type="radio" name="{{item.Country}}">{{item.State}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it is working as expected. Thanks for property binding